# How to compare dependent variables with different units using Grammar of Graphics paradigm?

Tags: data-visualization, ggplot2

My data analysis workflow is through R and `ggplot2`, in part because `ggplot2` discourages me from making 'bad' (misleading, etc.) plots. However, I sometimes would like to make plots that compare multiple unlike dependent variables against a common independent variable, like below:
[image].

This is usually done by adding multiple axes.  `ggplot` can't add multiple axes.

I realize that I have several ways around this: I could move out of ggplot for this type of plot, or I could probably hack something within ggplot.

My question is how I *should* deal with with this. The `ggplot` way to deal with this is by facetting, but often I want to facet by other variables. (For instance, with the pictured example, I might have collected the data at multiple locations and altitudes).

Is Grammar of Graphics just a bad paradigm for this kind of dataset, or is there some presentation option that would work well?

Comment: Multiple axes are nearly always misleading, and changing the limits of one or the other can change the whole meaning of the plot.  I think this was illustrated in some of Howard Wainer's work.

Comment: OK, but what is the alternative in the situation that I describe?

Comment: It depends on what you want to emphasize about the difference/similarity of the two DVs.

Comment: The general theme is that I'm trying to assess the extent to which the data track each other - to show that when one bumps up, the other does too. In the example above, you can see that for the first half of the data set, the data mirror each other - RH goes down when windspeed goes up, but that relationship seems to break down in the second half of the timeseries.

Comment: That graph is misleading as it strongly suggests the two variables move consistently in opposite directions: it is psychologically hard to see when they do not without it being pointed out (such as at 12am on 9/2/2008).  It would be better to reverse one of the axes and even better to do a linear regression of one against the other, plot the regression-derived values and only then add the second axis.

Comment: You can always scale the variables yourself and plot on the same axes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call me a heretic, but I completely disagree with this flame war on double axes; yes, they can be extremely deceiving, but only when you plot two things of a same unit (i.e. when their sum or difference makes sense) -- then the plot suggest that they have an equal range, which is usually not the case (like income of two companies).
But if you have two different units, this problem cease to exist -- viewer's mind instantly rejects the idea that values are important and focuses on co-occurring patterns.
Also if you want to show a nonlinear and lagged correlation, scatterplots and ratio plots will be completely useless, autocorrelation may be inconclusive and will show only a fraction of information and facets will hide the nature of the lag -- I see no better option here:

[image]
[image]

Moreover, double axes are great for a completely benign task of showing something in two linearly dependent units, like temperature in °C and K.

Finally, they are simply ubiquitous in physics (meteorology included) and engineering and none of those people feel wrong about it.

Comment: Disagree about scatterplot - pattern is pretty obvious there. Low values are followed by high values, high valuse by low values.

Comment: That's interesting provided the fact that the scatterplot is invariant to any change of temporal coordinate. You might have been able to detect that only on a connected scatterplot, which on the other hand usually looks like a tumbleweed for more than a few points.

Answer (score 1):

I think your graph can mislead about the relationship.  The following, which just reverses one of the lines, tells a rather more informative story about which changes first and shows when one changes and the other does not.

[image]

and would be better still if the one of the lines resulted from a linear regression of the red data and black data.

If each lines is a linear function of the original data, I would then have less objection to adding the two scales, even though it could still confuse as one would be upside down.

Answer (score 0):

Given the comments, I suggest graphing the ratio of one variable to the other. This is easier for people to track than looking at and comparing two lines. The idea is similar to the one highlighted by William Cleveland in one of his books where he looks at a graph by Playfair of England's imports vs. exports and converts it to one of the gap between them. However, with different scales, difference makes less sense than ratio.

The ratio may not have any intuitive appeal, itself, but it will aid the visualization.

Comment: I saw that plot when I googled Wainer at your suggestion. The thing I don't like (and reviewers will hate) about the ratio is that it replaces physically meaningful, intuitive units with hard-to-interpret units. I want to highlight the comparison between the two variables - but I also want readers to be able to see the underlying data. It matters whether windspeed is 6 m/s or 600 m/s!

Comment: How exactly does plotting the ratios answer the question that the OP speculated (which is in essence that the two series are correlated)?

Comment: If the series are correlated the ratio would be stable. But you could make three graphs, perhaps in parallel down the page, one with each variable and one with the ratio.